# Python to download pdf full papers from sciencedirect or scopus via api

Tags: python, api, download, scopus

I am trying to batch-load papers from scopus (sciencedirect) via api.

- The code below works for doi1, successfully 1st page only (maybe the paper is not open-access).
- I tried many other doi, like doi2, but always error 404 (not found).
- I tried using eid, same error 404, although it states it should, [here](https://dev.elsevier.com/documentation/ArticleRetrievalAPI.wadl)
- I tried using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59202176/python-download-papers-from-sciencedirect-by-doi-with-requests) too, exactly same (doi1 gave 1st page, others gave error)

Thanks for any help!

```
    headers = {
        'X-ELS-APIKEY': "keykeykeykeykeykey",
        'Accept': 'application/pdf',
        'X-ELS-Insttoken': "instToken",
        'view' = 'FULL'
    }

    _url_base= u'https://api.elsevier.com/content/article/'

    # doi2 = '10.1038/s41598-022-13702-3' # open
    # doi2 = '10.1038/s43586-022-00095-w' # no open
    # doi2 = '10.1016/0038-1098(87)90044-5'
    # doi2 = '10.1038/s41467-022-28902-8'
    doi1 = '10.1016/S1525-1578(10)60571-5'
    url = _url_base + 'doi/' + str(doi1)
    
    # eid = '2-s2.0-0023361241'
    # url = _url_base + 'eid/' + str(eid) 
    print(url)
    
    res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    print(res.status_code)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        with open('test1' + '.pdf','wb') as f:
            f.write(res.content)
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? How did you do it?

Comment: I did not solve it.
I tried to search again and found the same question, with some useful comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514069/requests-from-scopus-api-is-only-writing-the-first-page-of-the-pdf
It seems, although open access, some restriction for PDF loading

Comment: For the error 404, no idea, as I tried those doi on browser, they are all alive

Comment: actually I download the paper. BUT only the first page.  I don't know what happen.  I'm working on it

Comment: As mentioned in the post, I experienced the same. According to comments to the post I mentioned in the previous comment, there seem to be restriction to download paper via API, even it is 'open access'.

Comment: I confirmed that 1st page was returned due to limited permission. You may check by print ing res.headers, then you should see all headers including <'X-ELS-Status': 'WARNING - Response limited to first page because requestor not entitled to resource'>